# TypeError: Model.find(...).project is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, project

```
let totalProducts = await RentedProducts.find({
  customer: req.params.id,
}).project({ barcodes: 1 })
```

I just want to fetch the barcodes field but It is giving an error.

> TypeError: RentedProducts.find(...).project is not a function

I have also installed MongoDB nodejs driver:

```
"mongodb": "^3.6.3",
```

How to use .project() for minimizing the bandwidth by reducing the number of fields on return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are using simple find command you don't need project:

```
db.RentedProducts.find({customer: req.params.id}, {barcodes: 1, _id: 0 })
```